# Writing different language in manim

Tags: python, manim

I want to animate some words written in different languages in Manim. Everything is working fine when I am using the English language, but when I try to render words written in different languages, I get a UnicodeEncodeError. Any way to get around this? Thanks in advance

```
class TextOnTopEdge(Scene):
def construct(self):
    first_line=TextMobject("আয়ান")
    second_line=TextMobject("What do you think?")
    second_line.next_to(first_line,DOWN)
    third_line=TextMobject("Poncho will tell the stories ")
    third_line.next_to(first_line,DOWN)
    fourth_line=TextMobject("And Shelly will handle the visual thingies ")
    fourth_line.next_to(third_line,DOWN)
    fifth_line=TextMobject("PATH TO GLORY!!!!")
    fifth_line.next_to(first_line,UP,buff=1)

    self.add_sound("sound")
    self.add(first_line, second_line)
    self.wait(3)
    self.play(Transform(second_line,third_line))
    self.wait(3)
    self.play(Transform(third_line,fourth_line))
    self.wait(3)
    self.play(Transform(fourth_line,fifth_line))
    self.wait(3)
```

The above part is the Code

> "UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 522-525: character maps to "

And this is the error.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? Where's your code?

Comment: @AlexOsheter I am new at this. Can you guide me on how to post my code here?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is a good place to start. In general, before you submit a question, there's some info on the side. It's highly recommended you read it before asking questions.

Comment: @AlexOsheter I did insert the code as you asked, I would be glad if you could remove the downvote

Comment: I didn't downvote your post, someone else did. I just explained why your post isn't getting traction, and why you're getting downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

[Manim](https://github.com/3b1b/manim) is a Mathematical Animation Engine, and as such relies heavily on [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX). LaTeX uses an English font, and can only accept English text. [It is possible to add fonts to Manim](https://github.com/3b1b/manim/issues/525). I've also found a question on the TeX stackexchange [specifically talking about using Bengali](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99606/how-to-write-bengali-in-latex) in LaTeX. The top linked post provides a link to the fonts you'll need. Good luck!

Comment: Just to give it a try i tried the example in the post [It is possible to add fonts to Manim](https://github.com/3b1b/manim/issues/525) . But, now i am getting a different error. Latex error converting to dvi.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Text()` instead of `TextMobject()`
I fixed some bugs. Use it from [here](https://github.com/3b1b/manim/pull/1071) and replace appropriate files in your manim folder from [here](https://github.com/3b1b/manim/pull/1071/files)

And make sure you are using appropriate fonts for given language as menstioned in that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61512704/bengali-words-printing-out-all-wrong-in-manim/62492587#62492587)