# Bengali words printing out all wrong in manim

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode, manim

I had been trying to animate bengali characters using Manim. I used [this method](https://github.com/3b1b/manim/pull/680/files) to use pc fonts in Manim. Everything seemed to be working well until i saw the output. For instance, if i write বাংলা লেখা i get the output as (look closely at the output) বাংলা লখো. Most of the times it spits out absolutely meaningless words.

The code used was:

```py
class test_3(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        text1 = Text('বাংলা লেখা', font='Akaash')       
        text2 = Text('english text', font='Arial').move_to(DOWN)
        self.play(Write(text1), Write(text2))
        self.wait()
```

Comment: The ligatures aren't rendered properly, right? You should probably file a bug at Manim.

Comment: @lenz I don't think its about rendering. It looks like the unicode encoding is broken.

Comment: There isn't even an error code, so how do i find the bug?

Comment: It doesn't look like an encoding problem to me. In one version, KHA is missing and AA is changed to O. Filing a bug means you [open an issue at Manim](https://github.com/3b1b/manim/issues/new), explain what you did, what you expected to see and what you actually saw. Then it's up to the Manim developers to find and fix the bug, if they think it is one.

Answer (score 2):

Bangla texts can be displayed properly just by specifying a Bangla font in `Text()` or `MarkupText()`.

For example, if I like to display the Bangla text `আইনস্টাইনের সমীকরণ` in [`Kalpurush`](https://www.omicronlab.com/bangla-fonts.html) font, it can be done by:

```
from manim import *

class bangla(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        text = Text("আইনস্টাইনের সমীকরণ", font="Kalpurush")
        self.play(Write(text))
```

Here, the font is locally installed. Many [fonts](https://fonts.google.com/?subset=bengali) can be used directly from online via the python package [`manim-fonts`](https://pypi.org/project/manim-fonts/).

---

If you want to nicely show Bangla texts/sentences that contain inline-maths, you can use the LaTeX package [`latexbangla`](https://ctan.org/pkg/latexbangla).

Here's an example code:

```
from manim import *

class bangla(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        myTemplate = TexTemplate(tex_compiler="xelatex", output_format=".pdf", preamble=r"\usepackage[banglamainfont=Kalpurush, banglattfont=Kalpurush]{latexbangla}")
        tex = Tex(r"আইনস্টাইনের সমীকরণ, $E^2=(mc^2)^2+(pc)^2$", tex_template=myTemplate)
        self.play(Write(tex))
```

The output:
[image: bangla_ManimCE_v0 14 0]

N.B. The issue was also discussed on the Github repositories: [ManimCommunity/manim](https://github.com/ManimCommunity/manim/discussions/1993#discussioncomment-2249187) and  [3b1b/maim](https://github.com/3b1b/manim/issues/735#issuecomment-1050640271).

Answer (score 1):

Try to use ANSI Bangla fonts like "SutonnyMJ". If you are using Avro keyboard you can use Output as ANSI option like this,
[image: Avro Keyboard Output as ANSI]

Then if you have chosen font for example "SutonnyMJ", your code should look like this,

```
class test_3(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        text1 = Text('evsjv †jKAv', font='SutonnyMJ')       
        text2 = Text('english text', font='Arial').move_to(DOWN)
        self.play(Write(text1), Write(text2))
        self.wait()
```

Here I've replaced `বাংলা লেখা` with `evsjv †jKAv` (just ANSI form of the same Unicode text) which will render `বাংলা লেখা` as the font is now ANSI. I hope that Manim will support unicode fonts soon.

---

EDIT

---

I've found Bengali Unicode fonts to be working on Manim now. (24 March, 2021). I did this with Kalpurush font.

The code is

```
class FirstScene(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        text = Text("বাংলা অক্ষরে লেখা", font="Kalpurush")
        text2 = Text("Another text")
        self.play(Write(text), run_time=1)
        self.wait(3)
        self.remove(text)
        self.play(Write(text2))
```

See the screenshot below,
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

This is because of font type.
You should use bangli font. Try any font from [here](http://www.freebanglafont.com/)